# How (if possible) to optimize memory in this PHP example

Tags: php, oop, memory-management, php-internals

I am trying to understand how PHP handles memory consumption in these two examples.

#### Example: 1

```
   // foo.php
    class foo{
        public function __construct()
        {
          $a = new PDO(...);
          $b = new StdClass; 
          $c = new Reflection; 
          $d = new SessionHandler; 
        }

        public function w(){}
        public function x(){}
        public function y(){}
        public function z(){}
     }
```

#### Example: 2

```
 class bar{ 
     public function __construct(){}

     public function w(){
        return new PDO(...); 
     }

     public function x(){
        return new StdClass;
     }

     public function y(){
        return new Reflection; 
     }
     public function z(){
        return new SessionHandler; 
     }
  }
```

Now depending on the above two example, I would like to know if these two calls, occupy the same amount of memory, or in other terms which one would be executed fast.

```
$foo = new foo();
```

###VS

```
$bar = new bar();
$bar->w();
```

I understand that class `foo` instantiates 4 objects during its instance alone, while class `bar` has one instance when it calls the method `w()`. This seems like, `foo` would take more memory, but I believe also, php parses everything when it reads the class, even the methods that are not invoked, it seems there is no real difference.

Comment: So add timestamps and check, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe also, php parses everything when it reads the class, even the methods that are not invoked

Your belief is at least uninformed.

Parsing (**first stage**) is a different stage in the execution of a script, actually executing it is another (**second**) stage.

PHP does not execute any code prior to execution (**second stage**), it only compiles (**first stage**) the textual form of your code to a more compact, binary representation called *opcodes* - similar to the opcodes understood by the electronics in any CPU.

This is the reason PHP modules called *opcode cachers* exist - to cache the opcodes and skip the parsing (**first stage**) of the textual representation.

The most efficient way to do it memory-wise is to instantiate your resources [lazily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization):

```
class Foo
{
    private $x;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //keep the constructor as lightweight as possible, ALWAYS
    }

    public function getX() {
        if(!$this->x) {
             $this->x = new X();
        }
        return $this->x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**

```
 public function __construct()
 {
   $a = new PDO(...);
   $b = new StdClass; 
   $c = new Reflection; 
   $d = new SessionHandler; 
 }
```

For this example PHP is going to allocate memory for variables $a, $b, $c and $d. When constructor method finishes execution, ref-count for those objects will immediately hit 0, meaning that in next collection cycle they are going to be removed from memory.

**Case 2:**

```
public function w(){
    return new PDO(...); 
 }

 public function x(){
    return new StdClass;
 }

 public function y(){
    return new Reflection; 
 }
 public function z(){
    return new SessionHandler; 
 }
```

Methods w, x, y and z are each returning instances of various objects. These objects will be kept in memory as long as ref-count is > 0.

**Example:**

```
$bar = new bar();
$bar->w(); //Returned object is not assigned to any variable, so it will be destroyed -> ref-count = 0
$x = $bar->x(); //ref-count = 1
$x2 = $x; //ref-count = 2
unset($x); //ref-count = 1
unset($x2); //ref-count = 0, bye-bye object
```

In order to understand what is happening *behind the scenes* of PHP memory managament one might be interested in reading following manual pages:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.php

**To answer the question**

```
"I would like to know if these two calls, occupy the same amount of memory, or in other terms which one would be executed fast"
```

Well you are going to use all 4 of those objects in your script at some point (I quess?), so just pick a pattern and stick with it.
Speed and memory consumption will depend on how you will be using these objects.